# my js function is called after second mouse click

Tags: javascript, css

I want to check if background and text color of an element are matching or not, everything is fine except the fact that, `check();` is called after second mouse click !

```
function check() {
    if(document.getElementById("cimg").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("cimg").style.color) {
        alert("Matched");
    }
```

}

---

```
    function show() {
        document.getElementById("cimg").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
```

my Div(actually an image button):

```
    <div class="blue" id="bg1" onClick="check(); return show();" title="Blue"></div>
```

and cimg is the ID of the `div` where I want to view changes.
P.S: any jQuery/CSS/PHP answers are welcome!

Comment: Hey ThiefMaster♦, those two functions are separate, and i need'em in the same manner, so kindly preserve the integrity of Question asked, and first try to answer'em instead of editing'em !

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis of your function and your first function doesn't enclosed properly

```
function check() {
    if(document.getElementById("cimg").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("cimg").style.color) {
        alert("Matched");
    }
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJjWz/)

Comment: well, thanks for fiddle, but still in vain, also please give line no. in which i have forgotten parenthesis plus i think the second function should be in onchange event, what do you think ?

Comment: You need to put the curly bracket after the `if` statement at line number 5

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide else statement for `check()` function it will not return anything on first run but will run `show()` function and set bg color to blue then on next click you have match on `check()` function.

```
function check() {
    if(document.getElementById("cimg").style.backgroundColor == document.getElementById("cimg").style.color) {
        alert("Matched");
    } else {
        alert("No Match");
    }
}
```